# Regexp.escape adds weird escapes to a plain space

Tags: ruby

I stumbled over this problem using the following simplified example:

```
line = searchstring.dup
line.gsub!(Regexp.escape(searchstring)) { '' }
```

My understanding was, that for every `String` stored in `searchstring`, the `gsub!` would cause that `line` is afterwards empty. Indeed, this is the case for many strings, but not for this case:

```
searchstring =  "D "
line = searchstring.dup
line.gsub!(Regexp.escape(searchstring)) { '' }
p line
```

It turns out, that `line` is printed as `"D "` afterwards, i.e. no replacement had been performed.

This happens to any `searchstring` containing a space. Indeed, if I do a

```
p(Regexp.escape(searchstring))
```

for my example, I see `"D\\ "` being printed, while I would expect to get `"D "` instead. Is this a bug in the Ruby core library, or did I misuse the `escape` function?

Some background: In my concrete application, where this simplified example is derived from, I just want to do a literal string replacement inside a long string, in the following way:

```
REPLACEMENTS.each do
  |from, to|
  line.chomp!
  line.gsub!(Regexp.escape(from)) { to }      
end
```

. I'm using `Regexp.escape` just as a safety measure in the case that the string being replaced contains some regex metacharacter.

I'm using the Cygwin port of MRI Ruby 2.6.4.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> This happens to any `searchstring` containing a space. Indeed, if I do a
>
> ```
> p(Regexp.escape(searchstring))
> ```
>
> for my example, I see `"D\\ "` being printed, while I would expect to get `"D "` instead. Is this a bug in the Ruby core library, or did I misuse the `escape` function?

This looks to be a bug. In my opinion, whitespace is not a `Regexp` meta character, there is no need to escape it.

> Some background: In my concrete application, where this simplified example is derived from, I just want to do a literal string replacement inside a long string […]

If you want to do literal string replacement, then don't use a `Regexp`. Just use a literal string:

```ruby
line.gsub!(from, to)
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> line.gsub!(Regexp.escape(searchstring)) { '' }
> ```
>
> My understanding was, that for every String stored in searchstring, the gsub! would cause that line is afterwards empty.

Your understanding is incorrect. The guarantee in the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Regexp.html#method-c-escape) is

> For any string, `Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(str))=~str` will be true.

This does hold for your example

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("D "))=~"D " # => 0
```

therefore this is what your code should look like

```
line.gsub!(Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(searchstring))) { '' }
```

As for why this is the case, there *used* to be a bug where `Regex.escape` would incorrectly handle space characters:

```
# in Ruby 1.8.4
Regex.escape("D ") # => "D\\s"
```

My guess is they tried to keep the [fix](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/f50984366b923176b4e5f10efd87e0a85829afa8) as simple as possible by replacing `'s'` with `' '`. Technically this does add an unnecessary escape character but, again, that does not break the intended use of the method.